# IdentityServer4 in virtual directory

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Is it safe to host identityserver4 within a virtual folder in IIS alongside the mvc client application in another virtual folder?

For example, the below structure shows how we are planning to go about it in Azure App Service. The below routes are within a single web application under multiple IIS virtual folders:

domain.com - static html website virtual folder

domain.com/auth - identityserver4 virtual folder

domain.com/app - Asp.net core mvc web app (identityserver4 client) virtual folder

Will there be any issues with cookies/tokens since identityserver4 and the mvc application are on the same domain? Due to client requirements, we cannot host them in separate sub domains.

Thanks.

Comment: Why should it be? Cookies are stored in the browser on the client who visits the website...

Comment: @Tseng That is my understanding. However, would prefer to get clarification on whether this is explicity supported by identityserver4. Since this involves security, I would rather err on the safer side.